# Название кнопки и упоминание о ней имеют различное наименование

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице проверок. Нужно либо исправить строку, либо переименовать кнопку для единообразия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил надпись кнопки на «Действия не требуются». Новые строки будут доступны в ближайшей сборке.